# PHP function eval() with a large amount of code

Tags: php

I am having problems using eval() with a large PHP file.

This code is working fine:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('short_code.php');
eval($str);
?>
```

but

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('long_code.php');
eval($str);
?>
```

does not work.  I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '4' (T_LNUMBER) in /var/www/html/long_code.php(1516) : eval()'d code
```

Notes:

1. files short_code.php and long_code.php work fine without `eval()` and do not
   have any syntax errors
2. when I used `eval()`, I removed `<?php` and `?>` tag from start/end files
3. short_code.php has 147 Lines and 16036 Characters. long_code.php has
   1517 Lines and 181778 Characters.

Is this problem caused by a large file (long_code.php), or by something else?

Comment: I don't know the issue, but why not just `include('long_code.php');`?

Comment: i cant use include, i want to use eval() only

Comment: Just out of morbid curiosity, what is line 1516 and surrounding lines?

Comment: i used 
eval(my_function('xxxxxxxxxx....'));
xxxxxxx... is Encrypted code
line 1516 is: PhljYTUG'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please , try to use the following code and don't remove `<?php` and `?>` tags from start/end files that you get :

```
  <?php
   $str = file_get_contents('long_code.php');
   eval('?>'.$str.'<?php;');
   ?>
```

Comment: did you keep every thing as its at your file? just copy this code and try again and let me know

Comment: now , do u have solution without php start/end tags? or not work always without php tags?

Comment: it is better to understand eval from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: An explanation of the problem and your solution would be helpful.